# How to make results of a thread operation visible to all other threads in a process?

Tags: c, multithreading, fork

Here's the example code which I used to realize that this isn't happening. My goal is for the parent to see the change the child made to `myint` in `struct ss` (in this particular example, I'd want the parent to print `PARENT myint = 1`, or whatever value the child sets).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ss {
  int myint;
};

int main(void) {
  int pid;
  struct ss *s = (struct ss *)malloc(sizeof(struct ss));
  s->myint = 0;
  if ((pid = fork()) < 0) return 1;
  switch (pid) {
    case -1: return 1;
    case 0:
      printf("CHILD address = %p\n", s);
      s->myint = 1;
      printf("CHILD myint = %d\n", s);
      printf("CHILD done.\n");
      // free(s);
      return 0;
    default:
      printf("PARENT address = %p\n", s);
      waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
      printf("PARENT myint = %d\n", s->myint);
      printf("PARENT done.\n");
      break;
  }
  free(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Here's one of the outputs I get:

```
PARENT address = 0x1a79010
CHILD address = 0x1a79010
CHILD myint = 1
CHILD done.
PARENT myint = 0
PARENT done.
```

TBH, this has me completely baffled: how is it both PARENT and CHILD have the same address, but clearly, for some reason the parent doesn't see the value the child wrote to this address? Moreover, I thought all memory except the call stack is shared between threads of a process. Is there some trivial error I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Well because you're not using threads! The parent and child are different processes, so when the child writes into the address, the kernel will copy the memory page so it gets a private copy, and map it into the child read-write at the same address.

Comment: So the (same) address in the parent and child is mapped to different RAM when the child starts using it (in a typical implementation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fork()` does not start new thread, it does clone the whole process. So after `fork()` you've got two processes with identical memory, so variable addresses are the same.

Answer (score 0):

As willys say. If you want to realize your goal, you may want to use POSIX pthread to create the threads.

Answer (score 0):

I had answer it in another topic, here is my answer:
You are using fork(). It creates a process that is a exactly copy of your actual process, but it don't share the same memory. If you use threads all the memory addressing is going to be shared and you need to synchronized the access to the shared memory position in order to satisfy the data's consistency.